# rails console returns false when require redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have just started using redis been having a little diffculty setting up  redis with my rails application. My redis server is running but when i go to the rails console and type `require 'redis'` i get a false value. My question is how do i fix that after installed the  `gem 'redis', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.3'`. Where do i require redis at on my rails application so that can connect to redis.

rails console

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'redis'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> require 'redis'
=> false
irb(main):003:0> reload!
Reloading...
=> true
irb(main):004:0> require 'redis'
=> false
irb(main):005:0>
```

Comment: it does the same for `dalli` or interestingly try `require 'rails'`, but it doesn't mean it is not present. it is just not loaded since it is already loaded. If you have configured it properly it is included/initialized with the server start

Answer (score 2):

If yo take a look at the documentation about [require](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require)

> Loads the given name, returning true if successful and false if the feature is already loaded.

so when you run the rails console there are a lot of gems allready loaded and you can start using it, without requiring.

Probably you have in the config/initializers a ruby initializer with this content:

```
require 'redis'
require 'redis/objects'
```

when you have this loaded you can start using Redis in the console.

```
irb(main):043:0> my_redis = Redis.new(:host => ::APP_CONFIG[:redis_server][:host],
                          :port => ::APP_CONFIG[:redis_server][:port],
                          :timeout => ::APP_CONFIG[:redis_server][:timeout]
                         )
irb(main):044:1* irb(main):045:1* irb(main):046:1> => #<Redis client v3.0.7 for redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0>
irb(main):047:0> my_redis.set "foo", [1, 2, 3].to_json
=> "OK"
irb(main):048:0> JSON.parse(my_redis.get("foo"))
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

finally, when you try to load a library that isn't present it gives you an error

```
irb(main):023:0> require 'patata'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- patata
```

for a redis configuration just create the files `config/initializers/redis.rb` and `config/redis.yml` see this gist [gist see this](https://gist.github.com/pubis/1459506)

with the code:

```
#config/initializers/redis.rb
require 'redis'
require 'redis/objects'

REDIS_CONFIG = YAML.load( File.open( Rails.root.join("config/redis.yml") ) ).symbolize_keys
dflt = REDIS_CONFIG[:default].symbolize_keys
cnfg = dflt.merge(REDIS_CONFIG[Rails.env.to_sym].symbolize_keys) if REDIS_CONFIG[Rails.env.to_sym]

$redis = Redis.new(cnfg)
Redis::Objects.redis = $redis
#$redis_ns = Redis::Namespace.new(cnfg[:namespace], :redis => $redis) if cnfg[:namespace]

# To clear out the db before each test
$redis.flushdb if Rails.env = "test"
```

and

```
#config/redis.yml
default:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
development:
  db: 0
#  namespace: appname_dev
test:
  db: 1
#  namespace: appname_test
production:
  db: 2
  host: 192.168.1.100
#  namespace: appname_prod
```

finally the admitted and default parameters for redis client initializer are:

```
 DEFAULTS = {
      :url => lambda { ENV["REDIS_URL"] },
      :scheme => "redis",
      :host => "127.0.0.1",
      :port => 6379,
      :path => nil,
      :timeout => 5.0,
      :password => nil,
      :db => 0,
      :driver => nil,
      :id => nil,
      :tcp_keepalive => 0,
      :reconnect_attempts => 1,
      :inherit_socket => false
    }
```

Comment: what i did was i added redis gem to my gemfile then in my cable.yml file i `development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1`  so i dont know if i have to configure something else in my config/initializer cause my redis-server running. and is their a certain place to put the default redis information like the port, localhost, password in my rails application @anquegi

Comment: I think that the best way is to write an initializer, like suggested here https://gist.github.com/pubis/1459506, then store your variables in a yml file, then you could start use that object in the console or rails app. Is more or less like the answer